# Unable to install genism on google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, word-embedding

I'm trying to insall genism on google colab instance using the following command:

```
!pip install genism
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement genism (from versions: )
>       No matching distribution found for genism

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
!pip install gensim
```

?

(note spelling of "gensim" in my answer vs the spelling of "genism" in your question)

Answer (score 0):

I am getting a value error after installing gensim:[when i try to call a function]

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 **from gensim.test.utils import common_texts**

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/gensim/_matutils.pyx in init gensim._matutils()

ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33508267)